# Duplicate and Unique formatting in same column?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to apply both a duplicate and a unique format to a column?

I know that a value can only be one, but what if I'm applying the unique rule to say, **Col 1** and **Col 2** (checking for values that are missing in either columns), but I also want to check for duplicate entries in **Col 2** since that data are barcode numbers scanned by the user.

Ideally I'd like to let a user know that they've scanned an item twice.

I initially thought that if I highlight a cell to indicate unique, but change the text color to indicate that it's a duplicate, that it would work since the formatting doesn't collide. Just wanna know if there's a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

A conditional format will contain both fill and font color. You can't set the fill with one rule and a font color with another. The latter will set the fill color, too. You will need to create a new rule that has the logic you require to identify unique and duplicate (although it's not quite clear how a unique value can be a duplicate at the same time).